# Как расположить текст элемента списка по центру изображения получаемого из псевдоэлемента before?

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Текст элемента первого списка состоит из двух строк, остальные из одной. Если бы все состояли из одной, тогда понятно. "Игра" с отступами и/или отступами первого элемента, наверное не то? И не сработал почему-то принудительный перенос word-wrap: pre-line после слова "...компаний..." (хотя со случаем выше - перенос работает, на изображении текст в две строки, но это из-за инспектора кода).
Должно получиться в плане отступов и/или полей или по предложенному Вами варианте, примерно как на изображении.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
ul.ok-icon {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 5em;
    padding-top: 1px;
}
.custom-li {
    position: relative; 
    line-height: 1.3em;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom:1em;
}
.custom-li:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('https://suik.online/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/ok-icon-green.png');
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px; height: 40px;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  left: -4em; top: 5px;
}
ul.ok-icon li span {
    white-space: pre-line!important;
}
```

```html
<h3 style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #000000;"><b style="font-size: 200%;">Российский</b><span style="font-size: 200%; white-space: pre-line;">
программный продукт</span></span></h3>
<ul class="ok-icon" style="text-align: left; color: #000000;">
<li class="custom-li">созданный в 2019 году компанией <span style="white-space: pre-line;">аккредитованной Минкомсвязи России</span></li>
    <li class="custom-li">соответствует стандарту ISO 9001</li>
    <li class="custom-li">зарегистрирован патент</li>
</ul>
```

С уважением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал как проще и быстрее:

```
.custom-li {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```